# How do you call a getter created by solidity?

Tags: solidity, truffle

Apparently, solidity creates getter functions for public variables. How does one call them using javascript? (for testing within truffle)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just call them as you would any other function. The getter function has the same name as the state variable, so if you have:

```
uint256 public foo;
```

then you can read its value in JavaScript with:

```
contract.foo()
```

See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/02/making-smart-contracts-with-public-variables/.

Comment: `let foo = await contract.foo()` if you want the actual `web3.BigNumber` object rather than a Promise object.

Comment: Yes, or `contract.foo.then(...)` or, via web3.js 0.2x.x, `contract.foo.call(callback)`, etc. It's just the same as calling any other function.

Comment: Here's the Solidity documentation reference for those interested: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#getter-functions